# Auto generate a html table from a db query

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am a hobby programmer and until recently have only used ASP classic. I am using the Razor syntax and trying to replicate some code from ASP Classic.

The asp classic code from w3schools that i have been using is below

```
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb"

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT Companyname, Contactname FROM Customers"
rs.Open sql, conn
%>

<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <%for each x in rs.Fields
  response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
  next%>
  </tr>
  <%do until rs.EOF%>
  <tr>
  <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
    <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
  <%next
  rs.MoveNext%>
  </tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
```

I know most people are going to say use a webgrid. Yes i have done this and it is really slow so I am trying to troubleshoot it by comparing it to this.
My code in razor is the following

```
  var SelectCommand1 = "DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX); " +
                       "SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(tblTests.Name ) " +
                            "FROM tblTestsInEvents c INNER JOIN tblTests ON c.Test_ID = tblTests.Test_ID " +
                            "WHERE c.Event_ID = @0 order by c.TestsInEvents_ID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') " +
                       "set @query = 'SELECT Car_Number, First_Name, Last_Name, ' + @cols + ' " +
                          "from ( select First_Name, Last_Name, tblTestsLog.Driver_ID, Name, CorrectedTime, tblDriversInEvents.Car_Number "+
                                  "FROM tblTests INNER JOIN "+
                                      "tblTestsLog ON tblTests.Test_ID = tblTestsLog.Test_ID INNER JOIN "+
                                      "UserProfile ON tblTestsLog.Driver_ID = UserProfile.UserId INNER JOIN "+
                                      "tblDriversInEvents ON UserProfile.UserId = tblDriversInEvents.Driver_ID AND tblTestsLog.Event_ID = tblDriversInEvents.Event_ID) "+
                       "x pivot ( sum(CorrectedTime) for Name in (' + @cols + ') ) p ' "+
                       "execute(@query)";  
  var SelectedData1 = db.Query(SelectCommand1, EventID);
```

The inline code is this:

```
@{//grid.GetHtml()
  <text><table></text>
  foreach (var x in SelectedData1)
  {
    @:<tr>
    foreach (var y in x.Fields)
    {
      <text><td>@y.value</td></text>
    }
    @:</tr>

  }
}
</table>
```

The x.Fields is failing at the moment and I can't find an equivalent.
Any advice and tips would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What does its failing mean? Whats the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error is saying Invalid column name "Fields". the .Fields means something in ASP Classic but not in razor. Another way to word my question is how to loop through all the columns in my query result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more searching I found this to be the best solution. Thanks to @IUnknown for the pointers that go me to this point.

```
<table><tr>
  @{
    //This populates the column headings
    List<string> ColHeads = new List<string>();
    var col = SelectedData1.ElementAt(0);
    foreach(var x in col.Columns)
    {
      ColHeads.Add(x);
      <td>@x</td>
    }}
</tr>
  @{//This populates each row
    foreach (var tblrow in SelectedData1)
    {@:<tr>
      foreach (var rowcolumn in ColHeads)
      {
      <td>@tblrow[rowcolumn]</td>
      }
      @:</tr>
    }}
</table>
```

Basically I made a list to contain all the column headers as I was loading the heading row. I then used that list to get the data from the query and populate the table

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I presume you are doing ASPNET MVC. In that case I'd strongly recommend moving your DB code higher up in the controller, populating a specific model that you want to be rendered in the view.

So for example, you may have a DriversInEvents model (A simple C# class). You create a collection of this and populate them with the content you fetched from your db in the sql you have written.

You can then pass the collection to the view like

```
return View(driversInEvents);
```

In the view you can use something like the [MVCContrib grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid). Which is free on codeplex and great grid to start with. You do not have to create the grid with tables like this, the grid takes care of it for you, so that you can focus on customizing the look and feel of it.

PS: Welcome to ASPNET MVC.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can understand the concept of what you are saying and yes it will work for this example. But for future querys such as
`"SELECT * FROM tblTestsLog"` I don't think you above solution will work. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: 1. If you are doing a Select * you re doing it all wrong. 
2. It'll still work, as once you have the result you'll create the Driver objects' collection.
3. After that it is the same thing